# Apple Metal API inside macOS containerd, is it possible?

Tags: docker, macos, kubernetes, metal, containerd

I am working on a applied math project that utilizes Metal API for acceleration, I want to know if I could use containerd to encapsulate Metal API calls in macOS. Currently, all my apple machines are x86. I also have some linux machines and win machines. I plan to use K8s to orgranize all the machines, hence it would be great if macOS allows me to use Metal API inside containerd.

Comment: Maybe it can't. Containerd on macOS seems a proposal. [macOS Containers](https://macoscontainers.org/) links to [containerd discussions #5525](https://github.com/containerd/containerd/discussions/5525).